# Add properties to datacolumn/ultragridcolumn

Tags: c#, datatable, ultrawingrid

[image]

As shown in the above given picture, i'm working on application (using ultragrid and datatable) which reconcile customer data with supplier data.

There are various properties to reconcile data (exact match or matched with tolerance).

lets say may fourth row is exact matched, and first row is matched with +-50 tolerance.

In datatable i want to add following properties for qty (Common to customer and supplier qty)
1. Recon status, which can have following two values.
 (i). Matched
 (iii). Failed

2. Matching Type
   (i) Exact
   (ii) Matched within tolerance
3. Recon Tolerance : Tolerance will be shown for the columns which are matched within tolerance

Is there any way to show user a single column summary which will have string value like "Matched within +-50 tolerance" using all the above given properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Unbound Columns along with Conditional Formatting :

http://www.infragistics.com/help/windows-forms/WinGrid_Add_Unbound_Columns_to_WinGrid.html

http://www.infragistics.com/help/windows-forms/Win_WinGrid_Using_Conditional_Formatting.html

By defining your custom logic you will be able to format and display data however you wish.